# Excel adds empty row at end of output file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small but really annoying problem. I have written a code that analyses a certain amount of data and plots me the results in cell format. In the end the result shall be converted into a file format. This is my export to file:

```
Sub ExportToTextFile()

Dim WholeLine As String
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim sav_dir As String
Dim file_dir As String
Dim fsobj, fsfolder
Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim StartCol As Integer
Dim EndCol As Integer
Dim CellValue As String
sav_dir = file_path

Set fsobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fsobj.FolderExists(sav_dir) Then
       fsobj.CreateFolder sav_dir
End If
Sheets("Map_TXT").Select

Rows("217:1320").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete

FNum = FreeFile()
    StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
    StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
    EndRow = 216
    EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.count).Column
End With

Open file_dir For Append Access Write As #FNum
For RowNdx = StartRow To EndRow
    WholeLine = ""
    For ColNdx = StartCol To EndCol

        If Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
            CellValue = Chr(0) 'Chr(34) & Chr(34)
        Else
            CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
        End If
        WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue
    Next ColNdx
    WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine))
    Print #FNum, WholeLine
Next RowNdx
Close #FNum
EndMacro:
On Error 
End Sub
```

So no matter what i do, this functions adds an empty row at the end of my output file. This empty row is row number 217 and i have to get rid of this last row.
Can someone provide me with a solution on how to delete the last row in that file?
Thank  you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For writing the last line (when RowNdx=EndRow) use

```
Print #FNum, WholeLine;  '<<< note the semicolon
```